# How to do parallel computing in python 2.7 using MPI?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I have written a python code to carry out genetic algorithm optimization, but it is too slow. I would like to know how to run the same in parallel mode making use of multiple CPUs ?

For more clarity, another python code will be called by my code for, say 100 times one after the other, I wanted to divide this between 4 CPUs. So that 25 times the outside python code is solved by each CPU. Thereby increasing the speed.
Its highly appreciated if someone can help me with is ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

There are several packages that provide parallel computing for `python2`.  I am the author of a package called `pathos`, which provides parallel computing with several parallel backends and gives them a common API.  `pathos` provides parallel pipes and maps for multi-process, multi-threaded, parallel over sockets, MPI-parallel, and also interactions with schedulers and over ssh.  `pathos` relies on several packages, which you can pick from if you don't want all the different options.

`pathos` uses: `pyina` which in turn uses `mpi4py`.  `mpi4py` provides bindings to MPI, but you can't run the code from python 'normally'… you need to run with whatever you use to run MPI.  `pyina` enables you to run `mpi4py` from normal python, and to interact with schedulers.  Plus, `pyina` uses `dill`, which can serialize most python objects, and thus you are much more able to send what you want across processes.

`pathos` provides a fork of `multiprocessing` that also plays well with `dill` and `pyina`.  Using both can enable you to do hierarchical parallel competing -- like launching MPI parallel that then spawns multiprocess or multithreaded parallel.

`pathos` also uses `ppft`, which is a fork of `pp` (Parallel Python), which provides parallel computing across sockets -- so that means you can connect a parallel map across several machines.

There are alternatives to `pathos`, such as `IPython-parallel`.  However, the ability to use MPI is very new, and I don't know how capable it is yet.  It may or may not leverage `IPython-cluster-helper`, which has been in development for a little while.  Note that `IPython` doesn't use `pp`, it uses `zmq` instead, and `IPython` also provides connectivity to `EC2` if you like cloud stuff.

Here are some relevant links:

1. `pathos`, `'pyina`, `dill`, `ppft`: https://github.com/uqfoundation
2. `Ipython-cluster-helper`: https://github.com/roryk/ipython-cluster-helper
3. `IPython`: http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/parallel/parallel_mpi.html

Comment: Note that the latest stable release  of `pathos` and `pyina` are fairly stale, and a new releases are due out imminently.  At the moment, the best approach is to use the versions on `github`.

Comment: Also, if you'd like a fast GA algorithm that already leverages `pathos`, `pyina`, and `pptf`, then you might want to try `mystic`.  It's an optimization framework that's built to run on parallel/distributed computing.  It also has parallel ensemble solvers, which can provide global optimization at orders of magnitude faster than a GA -- if you have enough parallel resources.  `mystic` is also found at https://github.com/uqfoundation.